# need to block the user after 5 successive failure login attempt in laravel for 1 hr

Tags: laravel, authentication, blocking

need to block the user after 5 successive failure login attempt in laravel for 1 hr. Iam  using laravel i need to block the user for 1 hr after 5 incorrect login attempt. Please helpo solve this.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller {

   use AuthenticatesUsers;
   use  ThrottlesLogins;

protected $maxAttempts = 5;
protected $decayMinutes = 60;

  public function doLogin(Request $request) {

    // checking for multiple login attempts
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        Session::flash('error', "Too many login attempts. please try again in 1 Hr.");
        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }
}
?>
```

here i am getting the message as Too many login attempts. please try again in 1 Hr after 5 failure login but the locking time is not working as 1 hour as expected.

Comment: Updating $decayMinutes to 60? In your snippet given it is set to 5 which will lock the login for only 5 minutes.

Comment: but actually it didnt even working for 5 minut